# What is the mongodb equivalent of sorting over GROUPed BY field

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have two collections in MongoDB. Let's call one "objects":

```
{
    _id: 11,
    name: "Foo"
},
{
    _id: 12,
    name: "Bar"
},
{
    _id: 13,
    name: "Quux"
}
```

Another one is "values", that references "objects":

```
{
    _id: 21,
    value: "One",
    object_id: 11
},
{
    _id: 22,
    value: "Two",
    object_id: 11
},
{
    _id: 21,
    value: "Three",
    object_id: 13
}
```

I want to query "objects" collection, showing the number of incoming links from "values" for each document in "objects" and sort by that number, in an descending order. I want to receive something like this:

```
{
    _id: 11,
    name: "Foo",
    links: 2
},
{
    _id: 13,
    name: "Quux"
    links: 1
},
{
    _id: 12,
    name: "Bar",
    links: 0
}
```

In SQL, this is achievable using a simple outer join, GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

I can't use MapReduce (this must be an online query, not a scheduled job). I can't denormalize anything as "objects" and "values" in reality are collections of pretty large documents with lots of legacy code depending on their exact structure.

Any advice?

Comment: FYI The MongoDB implementation of mapReduce != something like hadoop. So it is not a "scheduled job". But basically you are asking for joins which is something MongoDB does not do. Any "merging" would be an external layer.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no JOINs. There is no way to get data from more than one collection with a single query. This means you need to program the JOIN on the application layer and then do your GROUP BY, also in the application. How to do this depends on the technology which your application is using.

Sorry, but this is what you get when you structure your data for MongoDB as if it were an SQL database.

Comment: We both understand that saying "sorry, your data structure is wrong" is very counterproductive, as radically changing data structure now in this project is similar effort-wise to a migration to an SQL database. I'm querying Mongo from Python code using pymongo, but I can make use of any advice, including how to query from Mongo console. It looks like aggregation pipeline can be suited for this task, but I'm stuck with which collection to aggregate over -- "objects" or "values"?

Comment: @SergeyMikhanov I don't see how aggregation could help you here, because the aggregation pipeline can only get data from one collection either. Porting to SQL is an option you might consider: You seem to already have an SQL database built in MongoDB.